# Linux short by symbol

Tags: regex, bash, sorting, data-processing

lets say I got this file:

```
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/index.jsp?_requestid=839
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/index.jsp?_requestid=859
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/index.jsp?_requestid=886
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/index.jsp?_requestid=897
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/index.jsp?source=EENT042114500148N&_requestid=26&wtSlotClick=1-006Y3D-1-4&rel=nofollow
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/index.jsp?token=46e134202bdd498c3369812e93c040122ecaf6b3
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/index.jsp?token=Ae18464df3d728b2aa98286e843cd38cfa82c49d1&B2B_GTM=
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/optin/optInEmailPopup.jsp?displayMode=1&from=businessCenter&bref=IBD903j370921100&wtLinkName=Subscribenow&wtLinkLoc=RN
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/phones/phone_details_main.jsp?_DARGS=/business/templates/od_page_begin.jsp.pageLogoutForm
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/policies/site_access.jsp;dsessionid=EBS51RW00NBS3B4R0ENCFEY?wtLinkName=TermsOfUse&wtLinkLoc=FTR
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/shop/shop_cru_home.jsp?_DARGS=/business/shop/shop_cru_home.jsp.form_1
https://www.wireless.miau.com/pct/contract_acceptance/agreement.jsp?_DARGS=/pct/contract_acceptance/business_agreement_frag.jsp.pageBusinessForm
https://xdme.wireless.miau.com/jsp/login/login.jsp?Exp=Y&FP=Y
https://youachieve.miau.com/news.cfm?id=1204
https://youachieve.miau.com/news.cfm?id=1214
```

And I want this output:

```
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/index.jsp?_requestid=839
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/index.jsp?source=EENT042114500148N&_requestid=26&wtSlotClick=1-006Y3D-1-4&rel=nofollow
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/index.jsp?token=46e134202bdd498c3369812e93c040122ecaf6b3
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/index.jsp?token=Ae18464df3d728b2aa98286e843cd38cfa82c49d1&B2B_GTM=
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/optin/optInEmailPopup.jsp?displayMode=1&from=businessCenter&bref=IBD903j370921100&wtLinkName=Subscribenow&wtLinkLoc=RN
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/phones/phone_details_main.jsp?_DARGS=/business/templates/od_page_begin.jsp.pageLogoutForm
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/policies/site_access.jsp;dsessionid=EBS51RW00NBS3B4R0ENCFEY?wtLinkName=TermsOfUse&wtLinkLoc=FTR
https://www.wireless.miau.com/business/shop/shop_cru_home.jsp?_DARGS=/business/shop/shop_cru_home.jsp.form_1
https://www.wireless.miau.com/pct/contract_acceptance/agreement.jsp?_DARGS=/pct/contract_acceptance/business_agreement_frag.jsp.pageBusinessForm
https://xdme.wireless.miau.com/jsp/login/login.jsp?Exp=Y&FP=Y
https://youachieve.miau.com/news.cfm?id=1204
```

I want to eliminate those that have several URLs with the same parameter but different values, I am trying this:

```
sort -u -t "=" -k1
```

and this:

```
sort -u -t "=" -k2
```

But I don't happen to succeed. Thank you very much

Comment: What do you want for: `url/index?p1=1&p2=2` and `url/index?p2=3&p1=4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort -u -t "=" -k1,1
```

will do what you want. The `,1` tells sort to stop at key position 1 too for the key. Default would be end-of-line, not end of field.

Comment: That was goddamn nice, it works flawless, you don't know the favor you did me ;)